# C++ beginner: what is the point of using a variable by reference if using "const"?

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference

I was wondering about the logic in this function declaration:

```
CMyException (const std::string & Libelle = std::string(),...
```

What is the point of using a variable by reference? Usually you pass a variable by reference whenever it *may* be modified inside... so if you use the keyword `const` this means it'll never be modified.

This is contradictory.

May someone explain this to me?

Comment: @iammilind: passing numbers by const reference is a bit heavy-handed, much simpler to copy them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually reference is used to avoid unnecessary copy of the object.

Now, to understand why `const` is used, try this:

```
std::string & x= std::string(); //error
```

It will give compilation error. It is because the expression `std::string()` creates a temporary object which cannot be bound to non-const reference. However, a temporary can be bound to `const` reference, that is why `const` is needed:

```
const std::string & x = std::string(); //ok
```

Now coming back to the constructor in your code:

```
CMyException (const std::string & Libelle = std::string());
```

It sets a default value for the parameter. The default value is created out of a temporary object. Hence you need `const` (if you use *reference*).

There is also an advantage in using *const* reference : if you've such a constructor, then you can raise exception like this:

```
throw CMyException("error");
```

It creates a temporary object of type `std::string` out of the string literal `"error"`, and that temporary is bound to the `const` reference.

Comment: +1 for pointing out why a 'const' is required to bound a temporary object

Answer (score 3):

Some arguments might use quite some memory. If you pass an argument as value it will be copied and the copy will be passed to the method.

Passing them as reference will only pass the pointer to the method which is faster and saves the memory for the copy.

Answer (score 1):

For example you can only do this with const reference argumernt:

```
CMyException("foo");
```

Think about it and then it will become clear.

Comment: C++11's rvalue references would like a word with you. :)

Comment: @Xeo still haven't managed to get into that.  But yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Passing primitive types (`int`, `char`,..) by const reference doesn't make sense. Even for `std::string` I would argue it's not needed.

However, larger structures or classes require a copy when passing by value, so there's overhead there. A `const` reference simulates the behavior of passing by value (the outside variable isn't modified), but also prevents the extra copy.

Comment: For std::string it is very much recommnded, so that CTOR and DTOR are not called unnecessarily.

Comment: I'm actually wondering: will passing a primitive by reference ever be slower or more cumbersome than passing it by value? It seems 'redundant' to do so, but there is also something to be said for fixed calling conventions.

Comment: Passing anything by const reference could be considered premature optimization.  Never the less, the rule "pass class types by const reference, other types by value" seems to be ubiquitous.  Which is a valid reason for following it.

Comment: @Ajay And passing it by reference means an extra level of indirection in the called function.  Something which may be more expensive than calling the copy constructor and the destructor.  Not to mention the case where a non-const copy is needed inside the function.  A performance gain is not systematic---the justification for using const reference for `std::string` is just that everybody does it.

Comment: How a simple indirection can be costlier than CCTOR and DTOR call, at the assembly level? Most often CTOR and DTOR won't be inlined/optimized, and would incur jump instructions to them - too costly compared to `referencing

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not always necessary that whenever you pass any variable as reference it is only so that it may be modified inside. If the variable is passed by value then a copy of the variable is made whenever that function is called.

A reference variable on the other hand, uses the same object and essentially passes only the memory address (same as using std::string*, but with the exception that you cannot use a null memory address). So, when you do something like `const std::string& x`, what you're saying is:

```
1. The passed argument will not be copied. The same object will be used as in memory.
2. The function will absolutely not modify the object that it is handling.
```

If you think about it, using `const` makes sense when you're working with references and not otherwise. If you are making a copy of a variable that I pass and then modifying it, I couldn't really care less. However, it would be really nice to know for a fact that if you're not going to modify the very object I pass (as you will be using the very same object), I can strictly further define the process of my application under this guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

I generally pass everything as const - I never modify the parameters, by value for primitive types, by reference for custom types. Passing by value for primitive types is more efficient in most of the cases - consider an unsigned short - by value 2 bytes, by reference 4-8 bytes depending on the pointer size.